# Prove that as $ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L, \,\text{then}\, \lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| =|L|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, definition

Basically so far I have managed to break it down to the following :

$|f(x)-l|< \varepsilon$

then

$||f(x)|-|L||\leq|f(x)-L|< \varepsilon$

then squeeze

$||f(x)|-|L||< \varepsilon$

I'm not too confident with this type of proofs, so a push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by squeeze.  But since you've shown that $||f(x)| - |L|| \lt \epsilon$ aren't you done?

Answer (score 3):

Using the limit definition: we have $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ so for $\epsilon>0$ we find $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ imply $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ but with your inequality which we can deduced it from the triangle inequality we have 
$||f(x)|-|L||\le|f(x)-L| <\epsilon$ hence we have
$$\lim\limits_{x\to a}|f(x)|=|L|$$

Comment: Good night my bro :+)

Answer (score 2):

You have done it right. The proof is completed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition:

$$ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L \implies |f(x)-L|< \varepsilon \,\text{whenever} \,|x-a| < \delta$$ and so $$ ||f(x)|-|L|| < |f(x)-L| < \varepsilon \,\,\text{whenever} \,|x-a| < \delta  \implies \lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| = |L|$$